# Разделение строки JS

Tags: javascript, массивы, строки, методы

постараюсь правильно изложить свой вопрос, хотя это будет сложно. У меня есть ексель таблица, в которой кучу текста, я её вставляю в инпут на сайте. И этот текст сливается в одну строку. То есть все ячейки сливаются в сплошную строку. Дальше мне нужно разделить отдельные предложения по масиву, но я знаю что в каждой ячейке текст заканчивается на цифры от 001 до 999. Я пытался написать скрипт который будет искать "876 " и после этого записывать всё что было до этого в ячейку массива, но ввиду неопытности у меня ничего толком не получилось. Подскажите как это можно реализовать. Не прошу писать код за меня. Возможно есть какие то скрытые функции для методов или скрытое их использование о котором я не знаю.(До этого я пытался писать через .indexOf но результата я не получил)

Comment: пример строки что у вас и желаемый результат

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант 1 ->
Если у Вас ячейки с текстом в exel расположены вертикально, то можно использовать `textarea` вместо `input`. При копировании в `textarea` ячеек из exel весь текст можно разбивать по символу перевода строки - '\n'. Получаем массив строк. Далее чтобы получить необходимую строку в массиве просто обращаемся к ней по индексу, попутно за ненадобностью отсекая 3 цифровых символа в конце строки через метод `slice`

```js
document.querySelector('textarea').addEventListener('input',function(){
  let arr = this.value.split(/\n/);  
  let str = arr[2].slice(0,-3)
  console.log(arr);
  console.log(str);
})
```

```html
<textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Вариант 2 ->
Если мы всё таки используем `input` и каждая строка в ячейке заканчивается 3-мя цифровыми символами, то можно также попробовать разбить строку на массив через регулярное выражение.

```js
   document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input',function(){
  let arr = this.value.split(/[0-9]{3}/);
  console.log(arr);
  console.log(arr[2]);
})
```

```html
<input type="text">
```